# I can not get result after calling JavaScript function

Tags: c#, javascript

I am working with Javascript StopWatch in C# web Aplication. But I don't get output from javascript. Below is my code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
            var state = 0;
            function startstop() {
                if (state == 0) {
                    state = 1;
                    then = new Date();
                    then.setTime(then.getTime() - ms);
                } else {
                    state = 0;
                    now = new Date();
                    ms = now.getTime() - then.getTime();
                    document.stpw.time.value = ms;
                }
            }
            function swreset() {
                state = 0;
                ms = 0;
                document.stpw.time.value = ms;
            }
            function display() {
                setTimeout("display();", 50);
                if (state == 1)  {now = new Date();
                ms = now.getTime() - then.getTime();
                document.stpw.time.value = ms;
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="display()">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                Time:
                <input type="text" name="time"/>
                <input type="button" name="ssbutton" value="Start/Stop"    onclick="javascript:startstop()"/>
                <input type="button" name="reset" value="Reset" onclick="javascript:swreset()"/>

            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am new with javascript ,Where I am doing mistake?? Thank You...

**Udate**:Finally I get the errors and solved it. Here is updates solution for someone who want to implement JavaScript Stopwatch in C# Application.

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var ms = 0;
 var state = 0;
 var then;
 var now;
 ms = new Date();
 function startstop() 
 {

     if (state == 0) 
     {
         state = 1;
         then = new Date();
         then.setTime(then.getTime() - ms);
     }
     else
      {
         state = 0;
         now = new Date();
         ms = now.getTime() - then.getTime();
         document.getElementById('timeInput').value = ms;
     }
 }
 function swreset() {
     state = 0;
     ms = 0;
     document.getElementById('timeInput').value = ms;
 }
 function display() {
     ms = new Date();

     setTimeout("display();", 50);
     if (state == 1) {
                      now = new Date();
                      ms = now.getTime()-then.getTime();
                      document.getElementById('timeInput').value = ms;
     }
     }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="display()">
 <form>
    Time:
    <input type="text" name="time" id="timeInput"/>
    <input type="button" name="ssbutton" value="Start/Stop" onclick="javascript:startstop()"/>
    <input type="button" name="reset" value="Reset" onclick="javascript:swreset()"/>



</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks For All your help.

Comment: The first thing that jumps out at me is the second button <inputtype="button". Also, a bit more clarity about what is or is not working would be helpful.

Comment: I dont get anything in my textbox...

Comment: I am not going to answer this question as it already has 3 answers, but I am going to suggest you use http://jshint.com/ to validate/check your JavaScript code. =)

Comment: Thanks Paul, I didn't know about jshint.com - seems quite useful and shoulb be a great help to Hiren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some first steps:  (This doesn't mean that everything will work, but it will sure help.)

- As [JohnFx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8812362/50358) pointed out, make sure the HTML is in good shape.
- Give your "text" input called "time" an ID.
  `<input type="text" name="time" id="timeInput"/>`
- Reference the element using getElementById()
  `document.getElementById("timeInput").value = ...`
- If things don't behave properly, put `alert(...)` statements in the javascript to see where its going and what values it's coming up with.

Comment: `alert` is bad, use `console.log` and he can use `document.forms.form1.elements.time` to get the time element

Comment: @Raynos:  "`alert` is bad"?  What are you talking about?  As a diagnostic tool, it can be quite useful.  Sure, leaving it in production code is a highly questionable move, but it isn't simply "bad".

Comment: alert is bad, It's a mediocre debugging tool, use `console.log` instead. Alert can only show strings and it blocks the entire program.

Comment: @Raynos:  And sometimes blocking the entire program is exactly what you want - with a string displayed even! :O

Comment: I doubt that is ever something you would _want_

Comment: @Raynos:  Interstingly, I've actually wanted that very thing.  People can surprise you with the differing situations and needs that they have.  Sometimes a mediocre tool is perfect for a situation you don't normally run into.  -- And the reason I brought it up is that "alert" is always around (the poster is a beginner) and it does the job simply (again, the poster is a beginner).

Comment: Your showing people mediocre tools of low quality on purpose, you should be teaching them to use `console.log` instead. Or better yet a full debugger.

Comment: @Raynos:  Do you purposefully stuff your children into bootcamp before they've learned to walk?  Clearly you don't prefer "alert", but your continued assertion that it is "bad" is overkill.  Forcing "console.log" (with it's difficulties depending on the browser you're using) can be quite a bit of pain a newbie isn't ready for.

Comment: `alert` is only ok if the OP doesn't know what developer tools are and you just want quick reputation points from the alert showing the right thing in jsfiddle because he wouldn't know how to check console. Suggesting to use `alert` is a different thing and completely unacceptable, it's not 1995 anymore :/

Comment: @Esailija:  Wow.  Such prejudice.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one problem is this line:

```
 <inputtype="button"name="ssbutton"value="Start/Stop"    onclick="javascript:startstop()"/>
```

I think you need a few extra spaces in there.

Also you refernce `document.stpw.time` several times, but I don't see stpw in your html.

Answer (score 1):

- `onclick=...`, `onload=...` is bad.
- `javascript:` is useless.
- `language=JavaScript` is useless
- `runat=server` is useless.
- you don't have a title and therefore don't have valid HTML.
- your state and functions are global
- you don't use `var ms = ...`
- `document.stpw` doesn't exist.
- You probably meant to name your form `document.stpw` and `document.<formName>` is bad. Use `document.forms.stpw` instead.
- `setTimeout(string)` is bad.
- you don't end your `if (...)  {now = new Date();` with an `}`

Comment: Maybe it was for the negativity of the answer?  At first read it doesn't look like there's much advice about what the asker *should* do.  (It is there, though.)

Comment: This does answer the question `Where I am doing mistake??` though